# How to convert this complex JSON into spring boot and store in sql server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
[
  {
    "Name": "xyz",
    "age": "20",
    "socialMedia": [
      {
        "fb": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "insta": "bbb"
      }
    ],
    "languge": "eng",
    "country": "USA",
    "Experiance": [
      {
        "developer": {
          "companyName": "abcd",
          "years": "5"
        },
        "tester": {
          "companyName": "efgh",
          "years": "3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i am getting this json from  front-end and i need to convert this json into spring-boot code and store in H2(in-memory) database......

intentionally i am not sharing my code.....

your answer might help me to enrich my code ...

so, please try to give your best using advanced concepts in spring-boot

***Thanks In Advance***

Comment: Hi, I understand your reasoning for not sharing your code, but usually, it goes the other way around. You first share what you have done, and people help you to improve your codebase.

Comment: why do you want to store the data in one table? if i had this i will make many tables

Comment: you can save in multiple tables as well no problem

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can look about JSON data types: [JSON data types](https://restfulapi.net/json-data-types/)
The link includes that how data types present JSON.

Then you can configure object model for JSON data.